# How get python subprocess to run regex pattern without adding escape chars?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, subprocess, escaping, locate

I am trying to run locate from python3 using a basic regex pattern.

```
subprocess.run( ['locate', '-r', '\.[^\~]$'] )
```

But subprocess is adding escape characters to the regex string. This seems to cause it to break.

The completed process reports that it ran the regex string thus:

```
'\\.[^\\~]$'
```

How do I stop it escaping the regex string?

Comment: You do not have to escape `~` and you may write `\.` as `[.]`. And it seems the regex is fine, just it does not match what you expect. `'\.[^\~]$'` matches a dot and then a single char other than `~` and end of string. Try  `r'[.][^~]+$'` or `r'[.][^~]*$'`

Comment: Ah yes. This works: '.*[^~]$'. Thank you.

Comment: So, you want to match a whole string not ending with `~`, right?

Comment: yes, pls see answer below

Comment: oddly, yesterday, the shell seemed to accept the command only when the ~ and . were escaped. ho hum.

Comment: Yeah, probably you are not using a regex then since to match a `.` in a regex, you should escape it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174237/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-markling).

Answer (score 1):

So the question was invalid. But the answer, which is an answer to a different question, is instructive.

this pattern worked

```
'.*[^~]$'
```

It was not necessary to escape the chars I had escaped in the first place, as @Wiktor says in his comment above.

The confusion was over just how simple the basic bash regex is. In that respect, the above pattern is not quite as it seems either.

.* doesn't mean find everything as is usual. * on its own means find everything. The . merely matches a dot. So .* means find something with a . followed by anything.

To be more precise, the actual pattern I am using is more like this:

```
'abc.*[^~]$'
```

... to find all files with name starting abc. and ending in anything but a ~.

Oddly, this does not seem to work:

```
'^abc.*[^~]$'
```